# Connection to mysql server in SYN_SENT

Tags: mysql, tcp, rhel5

We are facing a strange problem from last few days between our application server and database server(Mysql): connection to database server from application server hangs in `SYN_SENT` state and after that we are not able to make any connection to database server on mysql port(3306). When we checked the `netstat` output on database server its in `SYN_RECV` state.

What I can figure out is mysql server is receiving the SYN request and responding also and its not reaching to the client hence `SYN_RECV` at server side and `SYN_SENT` at client side. 
I think `SYN_SENT` state should go after some time and because of this other db connection attempts to same server should not hang.

Does anybody have any idea how can we resolve this issue?

Out setup details :

**Application server:** RHEL 5.4,  kernel-release =  2.6.18-164.el5, x86_64

**Database server:** Mysql Version : 5.1.49
RHEL 5.4,  kernel-release =  2.6.18-164.el5, x86_64

Comment: Sounds like the stateful firewall is out of connection slots. What's the output of `/sbin/sysctl -a net.netfilter| egrep "track_max|track_count"`?

Comment: These parameters are not present in sysctl output, just for information: selinux and iptables are disabled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my provider in evenings. It looks like some router in the chain between you and target host doesn't proper work with [tcp_sack](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2883.txt). The solution is to disable it in **/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
```

But this is very bad for server, because it will **slow down tcp** connections. You should make abuse to your provider

Comment: This must not be a router issue. It could be resulting from an attack or a broken client (Apple devices like iPhone and iPad has this issue for example)